# Is the thermic radiation of humans visible in common UAV NIR cameras?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle

With a group of students we gathered some UAV imagery containing RGB bands (~490 - 660 nm) and a NIR band (near infrared, ~800 nm) in order to calculate the NDVI with this data. Our start- and landing point is included and with the spatial resolution of ~7.5 cm and we can clearly recognize our group of people.

When inspecting the data, we noticed that almost all persons have a clear, high NIR reflectance as opposed to the visible spectrum, where e.g. only the person wearing red is showing high reflectance in the red band.

My first thought was: thermic radiation!

But is this correct? I am not an expert on the topic at all and reading a few articles about thermic radiation, thermodynamic equilibrium, black bodies and increasingly confusing other things, I gathered that thermic radiation doesn't equal infrared, but can cover a wide range, includig infrared visible and UV light and rather long wavelengths. Apparently all sunlight is thermic radiation.
But I got surprisingly little answers to "which wavelength has the thermic radiation emitted by humans?", the only source stating an exact number beeing ["12 micron"](https://www.hko.gov.hk/en/education/radiation/ionizing-radiation/00296-radiation-emitted-by-human-body-thermal-radiation.html) ~1200 nm and others only giving vague words like "mostly infrared" (which is a wide range).

Can I assume that what we are seeing in the NIR image is our body warmth (mostly generated by our bodies, not the sun)? Why are some few people (e.g. the person wearing red) not showing strong activations then - can I assume they wear insulating clothing that "hides" their body warmth? Or are they "cold" persons ;)

Or is it more likely that it is the other way round, and the high NIR activations are NIR reflections from the sunlight, probably caused by thermal protection clothing - as somehow is the case for vegetation (which re-emits the NIR since it can't be put to use in photosynthesis and would only overheat the plant)?

---

**RGB IMAGE**, showing people are wearing mostly blue, green and black
[image: RGB Image]

**NIR IMAGE (near infrared, ~800 nm)** showing most people as dark dots *[dark means higher activation = high emittance in that wavelength]*
[image: NIR Image]

**Red IMAGE (red, ~660 nm)** where only the person wearing red is "clearly" visible *[dark means higher activation = high emittance in that wavelength]*
[image: Red Image]

---

It occurred to me that I could ask ChatGPT about this and it had a clear answer. But since it learns from us and sources like this, I am not yet willing to post or accept it as an answer, even though it might be; however I will post it as "material" that can be confirmed or refuted by humans:

[image: ChatGPT answer: The high reflectance in the NIR band that you observe in your UAV imagery is likely not due to thermal radiation emitted by the people but rather to the reflectance properties of materials in the NIR spectrum. While humans do emit thermal radiation, it is usually in the mid-infrared range, around 8 to 14 micrometers (µm), and not in the NIR range (around 0.7 to 1.4 µm).]

[...]

[image: ChatGPT answer continued: ... In summary, the high NIR reflectance you observe in the imagery is likely a result of the reflectance properties of materials in the NIR spectrum rather than the thermal radiation emitted by the people. Different materials and clothing types can exhibit varying reflectance properties in different bands, explaining the differences you observe in the imagery.]

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law "Mammals with a skin temperature of about 300 K emit peak radiation at around 10 μm in the far infrared". NIR comes from the sun and people appearing dark are good at absorbing those wave lengths. Normal cameras are sensing reflected light, therefore they do not work so well at the night.

Comment: Thank you for that reference :) I agree with the most part, but I'm not sure about "people appearing [= being seen, i.e. refering to the visual spectrum 3.5 - 7.5 μm] dark absorb those [NIR = 7.0 - 1.4 μm] wavelengths". Dark people absorb visual light, but not necessarily NIR. And if you are referring to the dark in the images above, dark actually indicates a high reflectance (low absorbance) - I'll edit to make sure this is clear.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. As "dark" I meant objects which appear dark red in your NIR image, without considering other wave lengths. But I did not notice that the scale was reversed so that dark shade means high reflectance. If the people are not naked you are actually analyzing how their clothes behave. Plants tend to reflect NIR as much as they can because the NIR energy from the sun is useless for photosynthesis and it would just heat the leaves. I do not know how much human skin reflects NIR but for sure that information is in the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Human beings do not emit near infrared radiation. At the temperature of 300 K objects emit far infrared and the peak radiation is then at about 10 micrometers (μm). Glass lenses are completely opaque for far infrared and therefore no emitted energy from people can never even reach the sensor of the camera. The lenses of thermal cameras are made of special materials like germanium.

What your images show are presenting the radiation that the objects in the image are reflecting (not emitting). The peak radiation of the sun is in the near infrared area and the sensors of the digital cameras are sensitive to NIR. Therefore the UAV NIR camera can certainly see the reflected NIR radiation.